# Timestamp php to jquery format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

im looking for the function in jquery, that giveme the same format of time, like this.

```
date( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP');
//the output is like this.
2013-10-30T18:10:28+01:00
```

I need this kind of format but in jquery, for put in my var.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither JavaScript nor jQuery have built-in library methods for doing this in one step. You can find various plugins to help, or write your own:

See [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

And check out http://momentjs.com/ or https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Comment: i found this is
UTC:yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'